# MFMailComposer Exec_bad_access - might it have something to do with initialization

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In a view controller i have a button which internally calls an IBAction and that internally calls the

```
        [self showEmailModalView:FinalEmail];
```

now ... in the showEmailModalView i have

```
-(void) showEmailModalView:(NSString *)email{

    MFMailComposeViewController *mvc =[[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
    mvc.mailComposeDelegate = self; 

    NSArray *mails = [[NSArray  arrayWithObject:email]autorelease];

    [mvc setToRecipients:mails];

    NSString*emailBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" "];

    [mvc setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES]; 

    mvc.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];

}
```

and then

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
 [[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now it works alright... for all the scenarios of email or delete or anything like that but right after completion of the code the simulator just throws a exec_bad_access and then does nothing....  can you help.

PS: i also found out that that when ever you are giving a release to the mvc as declared above the error is called. ant thoughts.

**Update:**

I did install the app  with only one change... **i initialized the mvc in the header file** and then just use the same statement. so now i am not getting the exec_bad_access errors anymore... i think it was frightened of the nsZOMBIES....Haha... thanks for your Help and support.. guys... Both of you....

Comment: Set NSZombieEnabled (if you are using XCode 3.*.*) or go to Edit Scheme, Run tab, Diagnostic tab and set zombies there (if you are using XCode 4) to see the exact line that throws EXEC_BAD_ACCESS next time you run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't autorelease this object, it's already *autoreleased* :

```
NSArray *mails = [[NSArray  arrayWithObject:email ]autorelease];
```

Instead of change to:

```
NSArray *mails = [NSArray  arrayWithObject:email];
```

Comment: good catch was trying out a different things but that is not the case... still the problem exists.. and while debugging it doesnot show any problem at all till i send the email.